# Shortest distance between (-2,0) and $y = \sqrt\frac{2}{x}$ - without using derivatives

Tags: geometry

I was solving math problems and wondered
If I could find the shortest distance without using derivatives

Let $A=(-2,0)$, and we have $y=\sqrt\frac{2}{x}$
I tried to solve it by using similarity, but it kept gave me a identity.
How should I start?

**Edit**
I tried using P(x,y) on $y = \sqrt\frac{2}{x}$
$\overline{AP}$'s minimum will be the goal
Let $$P(\alpha, \sqrt\frac{2}{\alpha})$$ and $\overleftrightarrow{AP}$'s tanget $\pmb{a}$ when $\overline{AP}$ is minimum
$\overleftrightarrow{AP}$ will be $$y = a(x + 2)$$
and it's vertical that go through P will be $$y = -\frac{1}{a}(x - \alpha) + \sqrt\frac{2}{a}$$
This should be tangent line of $y = \sqrt\frac{2}{x}$ at $(\alpha, \sqrt\frac{2}{\alpha})$
Because $\overleftrightarrow{AP}$ go throughs P,
It can be said that
$$\sqrt\frac{2}{\alpha} = a(\alpha + 2)$$
That gives us
$$\frac{2}{\alpha} = a^2(\alpha + 2)^2$$
$$2 = a^2\alpha(\alpha + 2) ^ 2$$

Currently I'm stuck at here
Is there any other equation, or other solution that can be helpful?

- Also I tried using AM-GM Inequality,
  $$x + y^2 \ge \sqrt{xy^2}$$
  $$x + \frac{2}{x} \ge \sqrt{2}$$
  $$(x - \sqrt{2})^2 \ge 0 $$
  But It didn't gave me anything..

Here's How graphs are drawn
https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/w9fpfa5t

Comment: IMHO In these kind of questions, you can bypass derivatives only in some **rare particular cases**, with much effort ; but in most cases, you will loose hours without any mathematical profit.

Comment: Oh.. do you mean that that question might not have solution without using derivatives?

Comment: It might be so. For example, in your calculation, the "other equation" (your expression) you would like to add is provided by the fact that the slope of the tangent is plainly the **derivative** of the function...

Answer (score 1):

The distance between $A$ and any point $(x, y)$ on the curve $y = \sqrt{2/x}$ is
$$
\begin{align}
d(x) &= \sqrt{(x+2)^2 + y^2} \\
&= \sqrt{(x+2)^2 + \frac 2x} \\
&= \sqrt{x^2 + 4x + \frac2x + 4} \\
\end{align}
$$
Compute the derivate of $d^2(x)$ with respect to $x$,
$$
\frac{\partial d^2(x)}{\partial x}  = 2x + 4 - \frac2{x^2}
$$
whose root is $x = -1, \frac12(-1-\sqrt5), \frac12(\sqrt5 - 1)$.
Hence the minimum distance is $d\left(\frac12(\sqrt5 - 1)\right) = \sqrt{\frac12(9 + 5 \sqrt5)}$.

You require avoid to use derivative. But the roots of derivative is not so comfortable. I'd advise to apply AM-GM inequality.

Comment: Thx for your answer!

Comment: (x + 2) ^ 2 + y ^2 >= 2(y(x+2)), right??

Comment: @Mineppl12, can you find some coeffiecnts $m, n, k$ such that 
$$
\underbrace{\frac1m x^2 + \cdots + \frac1m x^2}_\text{m} + \underbrace{\frac4n x +\cdots + \frac4n x}_\text{n} + \underbrace{\frac2{kx} + \cdots + \frac2{kx}}_\text{k} \ge {\left(\frac{1}{m^m}\frac{4^n}{n^n}\frac{2^k}{k^k}x^{2m+n-k} \right)}^{\frac{1}{m + n + k}}
$$
and $2m + n -k = 0$ and $\frac1mx^2 = \frac4n x = \frac2{kx}$ where $x = \frac12 (\sqrt{5}-1)$.

Comment: I thinkn I have problem with understanding your comment...

Comment: What does that mean for? 